# How to convert blanks to nulls in column with string

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, varchar, coalesce

I am trying to convert blanks in a specific column in my table to nulls. I tried coalesce and that is not working. I want the string values to remain, but the nulls to be converted to zero. Thanks!

```
SELECT col1, col2, coalesce(col3,0), col4
FROM table1 cross join table2
```

I get the following error message: 
SYNTAX_ERROR: line 1: All COALESCE operands must be the same type: varchar

Comment: `col3`'s type is varchar, right? You can't coalesce a varchar to zero, because varchars are strings and zero is a number.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the tables' structure as `CREATE` statements, sample data as `INSERT INTO` statements and the desired result for that sample data.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like col3 is a varchar, thus you can't use 0 (integer). You could do this

1. ```
   SELECT col1, col2, coalesce(col3, '0'), col4 FROM table1 cross join table2
   ```

or

2. ```
   SELECT col1, col2, case when col3 is null then '0' else col3 end, col4 FROM table1 cross join table2
   ```